# Подскажите алгоритм к вычислению постфиксного арифметического выражения

Tags: c++

Нужно написать подпрограмму для вычисления постфиксных выражений, например:

```
1 5 3 - + 4 * = 12
```

**Думаю что надо рекурсивно**

Comment: https://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C+C

Comment: [Вопросы–домашние задания](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043)

Comment: Я вот не пойму в чем смысл выражения `3 * 4 = 12`. Насколько я понял, вам требуется просто сделать расчет постфиксного выражения, и получить его результат. В таком случае операция `=` не нужна т.к. переменные в вашем случае не поддерживаются и выражения типа `12 = 12` не имеет никакого смысла

Comment: [вот пара/тройка реализаций на C/Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249546/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

- Идёшь по списку аргументов

  - Числа кладёшь в стек
  - Операторы применяешь к двум числам с вершины стека, результат кладёшь обратно в стек
- Результат выражения берёшь с вершины стека

Comment: Только если гарантируется, что все операторы бинарные. Для унарных(например минуса) нужно будет допиливать алгоритм

Comment: но там же все операторы будут бинарниые

Comment: ок, `n-арные операторы применяешь к n числам с вершины стека, результат кладёшь обратно в стек`